# Incrementing by 4, not 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is that when I navigate(click) the counter(a) gets incremented by 4 instead of 1(I'm thinking maybe, it's due to body+html selector). So, I'm wonder what will solve this, could I just possibly subtract 3 after the incrementation or will some modulus be of help somewhere?

```
$('body,html').click(function () {
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(test[a]).offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 100,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            // updating a bunch of elements here
            $(somearr[a]).css({
                "background-color":"#fff", 
                "border":"5px solid #ff6600", 
                "margin-left":"-5px"
            });

            a++; // CALLED 4 TIMES!
            console.log(a);
            if (a === 7) {
                a = 0;
                $(filler_six).hide();
                $(filler).show();
            }
            clearDiv();
        }
    }); //end of animation
}); //end of click function
// Clearing The Div's
```

Comment: Would you like to create fiddle for this trouble?

Comment: @Jack a is defined earlier.

    var a = 1;

Comment: Your complete function is called at least twice (due to the selector), so the only mystery is where the last increment came from.

Comment: @Jack indeed sir *scratches head*.... I'm quite sure on mouse click events the click is like a switch and will most oftenly fire twice. That may be it.

Comment: When you click on the page both body and html elements react to the click. Both of them trigger the animation on both elements, 2 x 2 = 4.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the selector 'body,html', it registers two click event handlers one for `body` and another one for `html` elements. So any click will cause the event handler being called twise because of event propagation. This will cause `a` to increment by 2 because the click event handler is called twice.

Then again you are calling the `animate` on both html and body elements in each click function which will cause the `complete` function being called twice in each click. Thus a total of `4` will be added to `a` in each click

Try

```
$('body').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop: $(test[a]).offset().top
    },{ duration: 100, queue: false, complete: function(){
        $(prvL).css({"background-color":"#fffeec",           "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"});
        $(prvO).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"});
        $(prvA).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvD).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvI).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvN).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvG).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(somearr[a]).css({"background-color":"#fff", "border":"5px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"-5px"}); 
        a++; //decided to impliment 4 times.
        console.log(a);
        if(a===7){a = 0; $(filler_six).hide(); $(filler).show();}
        clearDiv();     
    }}); //end of animation
}); //end of click function
// Clearing The Div's
```

For Firefox

```
$('html, body').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(test[a]).offset().top
    },{ duration: 100, queue: false, complete: function(){
        $(prvL).css({"background-color":"#fffeec",           "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"});
        $(prvO).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"});
        $(prvA).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvD).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvI).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvN).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(prvG).css({"background-color":"#fffeec", "border":"0px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"0px"}); 
        $(somearr[a]).css({"background-color":"#fff", "border":"5px solid #ff6600", "margin-left":"-5px"}); 
        a++; //decided to impliment 4 times.
        console.log(a);
        if(a===7){a = 0; $(filler_six).hide(); $(filler).show();}
        clearDiv();     
    }}); //end of animation
}); //end of click function
// Clearing The Div's
```

Comment: that works. unfortunately, I need $('body,html') due to FireFox not working without it.

Comment: @DanFraser if that is the case when you need to prevent propagation of the event

Comment: @DanFraser sorry `e.stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 0):

You bind on body and html so the event is fire twice.. (one for body, on for html).
Take care about multiple bind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a one-time proxy like this:

```
function oneTimeProxy(fn, ctx)
{
  var called = false;

  ctx = ctx || window;

  return function() {
    if (called === false) {
        called = true;
        return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
$('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(test[a]).offset().top
    }, {
        duration: 100,
        queue: false,
        complete: oneTimeProxy(function () {
            // your code
        })
    }
);
```

As for the additional increment, you need to modify the click handler:

```
$('body,html').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // the rest of your code
```

Comment: @DanFraser Isn't that much better? :) so now you still have to figure out that extra increment I've mentioned before.

Comment: it's beautiful Jack *High $%^£in' Five*

Comment: @DanFraser I hope you didn't mean that in a sarcastic way; btw, I've found the reason for the extra increment and added a fix for it in my answer.

Comment: no, I don't mean it in a sarcastic way - I actually love the code. I'm saddened that I forgot  about stoPropagation, but, I've not been scripting long. I appreciate everything you, Arun P Johny and the rest have done here. 

This issue has been resolved!!